unocss transformer-directives as runtime javascript
How I can add unocss transformer-directives directly in browser in plain javascript?
I managed to have a setup for running unocss directly in browser without any build tool but to have a truly tailwindcss I will need also to have a solution for @apply directives that can be enabled via https://unocss.dev/transformers/directives . But I couldn't find anything that could help. The way to configure javascript at runtime is at https://unocss.dev/integrations/runtime
The released module is https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@unocss/transformer-directives@0.50.6/dist/ and any attempt to load the ESM failed.
The page:
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>unocss</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@unocss/reset/tailwind.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@unocss/runtime@0.61.2/preset-wind.global.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@unocss/runtime@0.61.2/full.global.js"></script>
  <script>
    ocssPresets = window.__unocss_runtime.presets
    window.__unocss = {
      rules: [
        // custom rules...
      ],
      presets: [
        unocssPresets.presetWind({
          theme: {
            fontFamily: {
              sans: ['Roboto', 'Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
              serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif']
            },
            extend: {

            }
          }
        })
      ],
      theme: {
        fontFamily: {
          sans: ['Roboto', 'Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
          serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif']
        },
        colors: {
          customBlue: '#548ab7',
          customBlueLight: 'rgba(188, 211, 241, 0.2)',
          customYellow: '#fffceb',
          backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
        }
      },
      transformers: [
        //<----- to have this I will need a runtime to include
        //transformerDirectives(),
      ],
      // ...
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;

    section {
      @apply mb-4 p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded bg-blue-200;
      border: solid 1px blue;
    }

    .prj>h4 {
      @apply font-bold flex justify-between;
      border: solid 1px green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <section class="prj">test<h4>heading</h4></section>
</body>
<html>


I have the same issue
